# How to get the value from a filtered json Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I am workin on react and I filtered a json array, but now I just want a value from that filtered json array.

Let me explain, I have this on my json Array

```
{
  name:"name1"
  location:"location1"
  job:"job1"
},
{
  name:"name2"
  location:"location2"
  job:"job2"
},
```

I filtered

```
        var filtered = datas.filter(data => data.location == "location1")
```

and now in console.log(filtered) it will show the array.

But now I just want the 
"name" be shown on a string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Index would be helpful.

```
console.log(filtered);
console.log(filtered[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach apart from the other's answers, using filter, map and then join.

```
datas.filter(data => data.location === "location1").map(d => d.name).join('')
```